# GitHub post-hook doesn't work with our PHP script

Tags: php, git, github, git-pull, remote-server

We have a PHP script which consists of nothing but the following code...

`/usr/bin/git pull`

...we originally were using just `git pull`.

Whenever GitHub posts data to this script the `git pull` fails. We've tried using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php and storing the response in a variable and writing the content of that variable into a text file so we could make sure commands were being executed - and they were! We could execute for example `git log` and the text file would have all content of the git log response. But executing `git pull` just doesn't work?

Our server engineers suggested using the full path to the git install (using `which git` to find the path) and that is what you see above, but that too didn't work.

We're confused as to why we can execute git commands such as `git log` when GitHub's post-hook calls our script but yet `git pull` doesn't work?

Does any one have any ideas on why this wouldn't work?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the entire script?

Comment: @starlocke "the solution must be to hire new server engineers, right?" yes that would be nice :-)

Comment: @WaynnLue the entire script? The php script is literally just `/usr/bin/git pull` that was the entire script (because the command is wrapped in backticks PHP treats the line as a shell command rather than PHP code). So we're using PHP to trigger a shell command and the PHP script is called by a GitHub trigger (which occurs when we push changes to GitHub). We have found that we can execute `git log` & `git status` but not `git pull` or similar commands like `git fetch`. I'm thinking there must be a PHP permission issue somewhere but why allow `git log` or `git status` and not `git pull`?

Comment: What I don't understand is why...
(a) this is a post-hook issue [which hook, exactly?]
(b) this a php issue instead of a bash script issue [hook scripts are normally typically bash scripts]
(c) why your php script is so incomplete [where is the "<?php" tag?]

Comment: @starlocke A) ok the title is incorrect, but I would have hoped the explanation in the actual body of the text would have clarified for readers B) this is effectively a server issue where a PHP script can execute certain git commands and not others - in this case not executing `git pull` C) if you want me to add the `<?php` and `?>` open/close tags I can, but I honestly didn't think that was going to be a big deal for people. If you say "I have a PHP script, here it is" you don't normally expect the `<?php /*code*/ ?>`. Similar in JavaScript ppl pasting code dont include the `<script>` tags?

Comment: In my case, the apache user which handles the php GET/POST didnt have permissions to create/modify files based on the git pull. The solution I've seen from others is to create a flag file based on that GET/POST with php, then use a separate shell script/cron to check for that flag and then kick off the pull.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the code is being executed as a user with sufficient privileges. You can confirm this by running `whoami` in the script that tries to pull with git